# How to call a Gradle subproject’s task from a Gradle test?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project that includes a subproject like so:

```
Root Project
|----gradle.build
|----SubProject
|----|----gradle.build
```

The SubProject here contains a copy script that I need called when the root project’s test command is called.

So I have attempted to call the SubProject’s task in the Root project like this:

```
Task myTest(type: Test) {
    Project(‘:SubProject’).tasks.myCopyTask.execut()
}
```

However, this results in an error, “Could not get unknown property ‘myCopyTask’ for task set.”

**Do you know how this call should be done, and what the proper syntax should be?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a multiple things not working in your example:

1. You should **never** call `execute` on tasks! **NEVER**! Tasks are called by Gradles task system automatically and calling `execute` may break this system.
2. The closure (`{ }`) you use when creating a task is for configuration. It is not executed when the task gets executed, but when it is created.
3. Subprojects in Gradle are created and evaluated **after** the root project is created and evaluated. So tasks from subprojects do not even exist when the root project gets evaluated.

You can solve all these problems by using the `dependsOn` method with absolute task paths:

```
task myTest (type: Test) {
    dependsOn ':Subproject:myCopyTask'
}
```